# using imported class in constructor of another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Getting started with ES6 syntax, why does `MesageTester.Create("bar");` in Main fail?

I have the following in **src/app.js** (which is also the webpack entry):

```
import {MessageTester} from './helpers/MessageTester';

class Main {
    constructor() {
        //does run
        console.log("trying..");

        //causes crash "Uncaught ReferenceError: MesageTester is not defined"
        MesageTester.Create("bar");
    }
}

//is fine
MessageTester.Create("foo");

//for testing
new Main();
```

In another file, **src/helpers/MessageTester.js**, I have this:

```
class MessageTester {
    constructor(msg) {
        document.querySelector('#root').innerHTML = `<p>` + msg + `</p>`;
    }

    static Create(msg) {
        return new MessageTester(msg);
    }
}

export {MessageTester};
```

As noted in the comments, `MessageTester.Create()` works outside of Main, and Main's constructor is running.

In case it's relevant, here's my webpack config (as an aside- I'm not sure if source maps are working properly... might be related to the bug here but not sure):

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: {
        jistudio: './app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        ['es2015', {modules: false}]
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
            }
        ]),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true})
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: true,
        port: 3000
    }
}

module.exports = config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing s

```
MessageTester.Create("bar");
```

Comment: lol... thanks! funny how I was so sure it was something in the webpack config since I'm pretty much copy/pasting, so it had me doubting myself ;)

Much appreciated!